# From IEEE32 float to 32bit integer numpy array (example : audio .wav files)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, wav

I read some data which is stored as IEEE32 float in the interval `[-1, +1]` with

```
A = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype = numpy.float32)
```

But then I don't want to keep the array as `float32`, but rather, as 32-bit integers (in `[-2^31, +2^31-1]`).

I tried by doing simply :

```
A = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype = numpy.int32)   # that's wrong!
```

but it provides a bad result. (wrong probably by a multiplicative constant, or another reason?)

**How to read an array of IEEE32 float in [-1,1] into a 32bits-integer array in `[-2^31,  +2^31-1]` ?**

---

*PS : This would work, but I would like to avoid this naive way to do it :*

```
A = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype = numpy.float32)
A *= 2^31    
A = int(A)   # convert the data type to int
```

*if possible, because I imagine there is a more clever way to do it, without multipliying, but just by doing things bitwise...*

Comment: Do you want to get the raw bit patterns as `int32`s?

Comment: Is it specifically required that the output be the same as your example implementation, for example, `0.5` becoming `2**30`? If so, multiplying by `2**31` is probably your best bet. (Note that your algorithm will round many possible inputs to the same outputs.)

Comment: @user2357112 that's true, but only for inputs < 0.004 in magnitude, float32 significand is 24 bits only. There is another problem if +1.0f is in the interval, it will lead to an int32 overflow...

Comment: Is there a doc showing how IEEE32 floats are stored in 4 bytes (=32 bits), in which byte-order, etc. ?
Then I could try to convert this to int32

Comment: “without multipliying, but just by doing things bitwise...” You are not going to convert floating-point values linearly to integers more efficiently with bitwise manipulations. Multiplication and conversion are the most efficient because there are instructions to do each of these in a few cycles.

Comment: Here is an updated version of `scipy.io.wavfile` that adds 24 bit .wav files support for read/write, access to cue markers, cue marker labels, 
some other metadata like pitch (if defined), etc.: [wavfile.py (enhanced)](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476)