# Extracting data which is in Float32 format to int32

Tags: python, audio, floating-point, integer, wav

How to extract data which is in `float32` format (in the interval `[-1, +1]`) to an `int32` which is in `[-2^31, 2^31-1]` ?

Here is what I want to do (but more efficiently, i.e. without multiplications / conversions if possible) :

```
f = struct.unpack('f', data)   # data is in IEEE float32 format
f *= 2**31
out = int(myfloat)
```

---

Example :

This is the float 0.000000000 : `00 00 00 00`

This is the float 1.000000000 : `00 00 80 3F`

This is the float -0.000000000 : `00 00 00 80`

This is the float -1.000000000 : `00 00 80 BF`

Why these numbers for coding 1.000000 ?

---

Note : This can be useful for audio application, where .wav 32 bits IEEE float have to live togethter with regular 32 bits integer .wav files.

*PS : I recently asked a question about float numpy array -> int numpy array conversion here :
[From IEEE32 float to 32bit integer numpy array (example : audio .wav files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467556/from-ieee32-float-to-32bit-integer-numpy-array-example-audio-wav-files), but now I realize that this problem is not numpy-specific, hence this more general question here.*

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32 . It answers your “ Why these numbers for coding 1.000000” question.

Comment: Thanks @PascalCuoq. In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32#Single-precision_examples,  it shows that `3f80 0000   = 1`. However, in my data file, I have : `00 00 80 3F` for 1. Is this related to endianness ?

Comment: Yes, you are clearly using a little-endian computer. Read the bytes as a single 32-bit unsigned integer instead of four 8-bit unsigned integers to avoid the endianness problem.

Comment: Thanks @PascalCuoq. From what I read (fraction + exponent), it seems that there will be no shorter way to do what I want than to do 1/ extract the data as float32 and  2/ convert it to int32. 

I thought it could be possible by extracting data, do some easy things on the bytes order, and done! but this seems impossible : we have to extract the data as float, and then convert it to int.

Comment: If you want to convert values from [-1.0 .. +1.0] linearly into values in the range [-2^30 .. 2^30], multiply by 2^30 as floating-point and truncate to integer. If you multiply by 2^31 you are at risk of overflow for 1.0, but you can either test for 1.0 beforehand, or multiply by the floating-point number (1 - 2^-23)*2^31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your list with floats into an array and then define dtype, in this case 'int32'. Also note that in Numpy the dtype for float is 'float64'.

```
from numpy  import *


float_data_list = [1.2, 3.5, 5.1]



matrice = array(float_data_list, dtype ='int32' ) # define dtype
print matrice

output: [1 3 5]
```